# A group of X people of different heights line up in 2 rows.

Tags: probability

A group of X people of different heights line up in 2 rows. One row is behind the other one. There are an equal number of people in both rows (X is even). The only rule is that any person in the back row has to be standing behind a shorter person. How many ways are there to arrange the group?

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Put all the people into a single line. Of the first two people, have the taller step behind the shorter; continue this for each pair of people.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I translate this into mathematics?

Comment: It was a hint.  I thought it would be good for you to work forward from there.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the answer is (X!)/(2^(X/2)).